# How to load HTTP content in Webkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, https

How to load HTTP content in Webkit in objective-c?

The code I use:

```
NSString *loadedURL = @"http://www.apple.com";

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:loadedURL];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

If i post a link "**https**://www.apple.com" (with http**S**) its open correctly, but from HTTP not. Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether the App Transport Security restrictions are
disabled for all network connections, which means that unsecured http connections may be allowed.

**Steps:**

1. Opened my Projects info.plist file
2. Added a Key called NSAppTransportSecurity as a Dictionary.
3. Added a Subkey called NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as Boolean and set its value to YES as like following image.

[image]

Now clean the Project and Now Everything will Run fine as like before.